# Shopify slice function returns '<'

Tags: shopify, liquid

I need to extract currency symbol in Shopify template. So far I've written:

```
{% assign symbol = product.price | money %} //creates a variable which holds price with currency symbol
{% assign symbol = symbol | slice: 0 %} //should return first char out of a string
{{ symbol }} //prints the variable
```

Unfortunately last line returns the `<` char.

Right now I'm out of ideas how to make this work. I know that Shopify can display currency by {{ shop.currency }} method, but it returns currency name instead of currency symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the money format which is set in the Store Settings 
`Settings > General > Standards and formats > Currency > Change formatting`
there are:

- "HTML with currency"
- "HTML without currency"

By default they are `${{amount}} USD` and `${{amount}}`, but they are wrapped them in `span.money` because you are using currency switcher.
`<span class="money" >${{amount}} USD<span>`

Easly you can use the filter `strip_html` to remove the `span.money`.

`{% assign symbol = symbol | strip_html | slice: 0 %}`